# Regex match for whole string (not substring) in bash

Tags: bash

I want this to only output "match!" if only the single character "a" or "b" is passed as an argument.  Not aaaaa, not bcfqwefqef, not qwerty.

```
#!/bin/bash
P="a|b"
if [[ "$1" =~ $P  ]]; then
    echo "match!"
else
    echo "no!"
fi
```

Yes i've gone through some SO posts to get this far already.  Putting $P in quotes doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to anchor your regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

re="^(a|b)$"
if [[ "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "match!"
else
    echo "no!"
fi
```

btw this doesn't require regex. You can just use equality using glob pattern as:

```
if [[ "$1" == [ab] ]]; then
    echo "match!"
else
    echo "no!"
fi
```

Comment: The ^(...)$ wrapping is what i needed, the real world use case was strings longer than a and b

Comment: You might still be able to use pattern matching: `"$1 == (long string a|long string b|long string c)`, for instance. Pattern matching is typically simpler if the choices are quite specific.

Comment: @chepner Needs `@(pattern1|pattern2)`, no?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of `case` syntax.